# Помогите решить задачу javascript

Tags: javascript

Дана функция с тремя целыми числами. Задача - нужно отнимать от первого числа второе до тех пор пока значение не станет меньше третьего. Функция должна вернуть получившиеся значение, которое меньше третьего числа

```
 function sum (a, b, c) {
do {
    a = a - b;
} while (c < a);

return a;
```

}

sum(20, 3, 10);

При тестировании, решение проходит 3 теста из 5, что не так и как можно улучшить?

Comment: добавьте ваш пример

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Подсказка - решение в одну строчку может быть получено  с помощью целочисленного деления.

Comment: function sum (a, b, c) {
    do {
        a = a - b;
    } while (c < a);

    console.log(a);
}

sum(20, 3, 10);

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Дана функция с тремя целыми числами.

function f() {
  console.log(123)
  return 10 * 14
}

// нужно отнимать от первого числа второе до тех пор пока значение не станет меньше третьего
// Функция должна вернуть получившиеся значение, которое меньше третьего числа

function solve() {
  var [a, b, c] = ("" + f).match(/-?\d+/g)
  return Math.min(+a, (a % b + Math.trunc(c / b) * b) % c)
}

// Проверяем

console.log(solve())
```

Comment: это чтобы препод офигел?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, ну он же сказал - "Дана функция с тремя целыми числами" ;) Надо же хоть условие нормально формулировать))) Тем более, кода в вопросе не было, когда я отвечал.

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(a, b, c) {

    // Если третье число больше, то ничего не нужно выполнять, 
    // возвращаем первое число
    if (a < c) return a; 
    
    // Если первое и третье числа равны, то вернём первое - второе.
    if (a == c) return a - b;
    
    // для остальных случаев мы упростим вычисление, без циклов
    
    // находим разницу между первым и третьим
    // Добавляем единицу, чтобы результат был для числа меньшего, чем третье
    const dif = a - c + 1;
    // Вычислим сколько раз нужно отнять второе число из первого.
    const num = Math.ceil(dif / b);
    // и отнимем сразу без цикла сколько нужно раз второе число из первого.
    let result = a - b * num;
    
    return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum (a, b, c) {
    while(a >= c){
        a -= b;
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(sum(20, 3, 10)); // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Тест:

```
console.log(sum(20, 1, 10));
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

А должно быть меньше чем десять.

Тест:

```
console.log(sum(5, 1, 10));
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

А должно быть пять. Зачем вычитать если с самого начала `a < c`?

Если править ваш вариант, то будет так:

```
function sum(a, b, c) {
    // do/while заменён на обычный while
    // в условии нестрогое неравенство
    while (c <= a) {
        a = a - b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Можно решить без цикла вовсе. `(a - c + 1)` - сколько единиц надо отнять минимум. Если меньше нуля, то ставим ноль: `Math.max(0, ...)`.
`(a - c + 1) / b` - сколько шагов надо сделать. Округлять надо вверх: `Math.ceil`. Целое число шагов умножаем на `b` и вычитаем из `a`:

```
function sum(a, b, c) {
    const f = Math.ceil(Math.max(0, a - c + 1) / b);
    return a - f * b;
}

console.log(sum(20, 2, 10));
console.log(sum(5, 2, 10));
```

> ```
> 8
> 5
> ```

**P.S.** в предположении что `b > 0`. Иначе решение есть не всегда.

Comment: Но `console.log(sum(20, 1, 10));` и `console.log(sum(5, 1, 10));` в моём варианте выдают соответственно 9 и 5, как получилось, что у Вас по-другому? Да и логика кода говорит о том, что это должно правильно работать не вызывая сомнений. И ещё запись **a >= c**  - это то же самое, что и **c <= a**, просто перевёрнуто с лева на право. Если изначально **а < с**, то цикл не выполняется, и прога возвращает **a**, как есть.

Comment: @Опан, sum(20, **2**, 10) .

Comment: sum(20, 2, 10); // 8

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего хочу сказать, что тестировать удобно тоже циклом. Если задать изменения числа **а** в пределах, скажем, от 5 до 30, а числа **b** и **c** оставлять без изменения, то можно будет отследить, какая будет разница в выполнении задачи с   помощью цикла ***do while*** и цикла ***while***:

```js
function sum (a, b, c) {
    do {
        a = a - b;
    } while (c < a);
    return a;
}
function sum2(a, b, c) {
    while (a >= c) {
        a -= b;
    }
    return a;
}
let array = [];
for(i = 5; i < 20; i ++){
    array.push(sum(i, 2, 10));
}
console.log(array);
array = [];
for(i = 5; i < 20; i ++){
    array.push(sum2(i, 2, 10));
}
console.log(array);
```

Не трудно заметить, что с помощью ***do while*** даже если изначально а < c, то всё равно а не остаётся без изменений. А всё из-за того, что условие в ***do while*** проверяется после того, как происходит действие, значит получается, что действие должно выполниться как минимум один раз. От сюда вывод - цикл ***do while*** для решения этой задачи не очень подходит. Нужен цикл ***while***.