# Помогите пожалуйста доделать задачу javascript

Tags: javascript

Дана функция с тремя целыми числами. Задача - нужно отнимать от первого числа второе до тех пор пока значение не станет меньше третьего. Функция должна вернуть получившиеся значение, которое меньше третьего числа

```
function sum (a, b, c) {
do {
a = a - b;
} while (c < a);

return a;
}
//к примеру подставляю 3 числа
sum(20, 3, 10);
//возвращает 8, вроде верно, но при тесте проходит 3 из 5
```

При тестировании, решение проходит 3 теста из 5, что не так и как можно улучшить?

Comment: А какие именно тесты не пройдены?

Comment: точно не знаю какие числа дают на вход в функцию, возможно первое сразу меньше третьего

Comment: Я добавил ответ на Ваш вопрос, заданный Вами по [этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434402/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-javascript/1435161#1435161).

Comment: Ещё ошибка - нужно `while (c <= a);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, твоя функция должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function sum(a, b, c) {
    while (a >= c) {//я поставил >=, так как по условию задачи c должно быть именно меньше, чем a
        a -= b;
    }
    
    return a;
 }
```

Это должно тебе помочь